# Migrating from AWS RDS to an AWS EC2 running MySQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Yes, fellow SOrs, I'm doing it backwards. I tried an AWS RDS but the CPU seems to be spiking so often that I need the flexibility of an EC2 to run some fine tuning. I'm not a MySQL expert, so I'm asking:

- How can I create a setup on the EC2 so that it reads and replicates my RDS?

Ideally I'd do the switch in real time via DNS but first I need the EC2 to act like a clone of the RDS updating with any new data happening between now and the actual migration period.

Any pointers are much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Exporting.NonRDSRepl.html

Comment: What fine tuning do you need that can't be done with RDS? Also, have you tried Aurora?

Comment: I haven't tried Aurora. I'm looking to edit the my.cnf, run mysql-tunner and sysbench. Aurora has the same synthax as MySQL (might be a stupid question). I'm running a Wordpress blog that I need to convert over.

Comment: I am _very_ skeptical that you actually need to move to EC2.  What instance class are you running? And are you aware of RDS parameter groups?

Comment: Yes, I did use parameter groups to enable slow_query logging, nothing out of the ordinary happening there. Long story short, I initially used t2.small, then t2.medium as the CPU seemed to spike and leave me without credits constantly. Now I'm on a m2.large but it doesn't make sense to pay this much for a wordpress blog that only holds about 10-15 people simultaneously. Here are some SS: https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ext.scorpiono/public/so/Screen+Shot+2016-05-05+at+6.17.07+PM.png https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ext.scorpiono/public/so/Screen+Shot+2016-05-05+at+6.16.04+PM.png

Comment: I'm sure issues will happen constantly, how do I debug though on an RDS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why can't you use mysql-tuner with RDS?
2. You shouldn't need to run sysbench, since Amazon handles OS level tuning for you on RDS
3. Aurora is a drop-in replacement for MySQL and will scale better than any MySQL cluster you could setup on EC2
4. You should be addressing why your Wordpress instance is hammering the database so much instead of trying to optimize the database.

You should put a CDN in front of your Wordpress site and cache as much as you can to reduce the load on both your web server and database server. It looks like there are also [solutions](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redis-cache/) [out](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-redis/) [there](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-redis-caching-to-speed-up-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04) for using Redis to cache data so that Wordpress doesn't have to constantly go back to MySQL for data.

Amazon provides the [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) CDN, but I would also recommend looking into [CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201717894-Using-CloudFlare-and-WordPress-Five-Easy-First-Steps).

Honestly, given your number of concurrent users, unless you have tons of dynamic constantly changing content, you should be able to run your entire site on a t2.micro with CloudFlare in front of it with [cache everything](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172266-What-do-the-custom-caching-options-mean-in-Page-Rules-) enabled.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, Mark. 

1. Wasn't aware I could run it externally. Great news.
2. Thank you
3. Will check it out
4. Is there a way I could debug this further at a "code" level?

We do use a CDN via CloudFront. The site loads very fast, except when the RDS hits 100% CPU it goes down. Restarting apache on the EC2 usually frees up the CPU on the RDS and things are back to normal.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't caching much at the CDN. The issue is that Wordpress is going back to the database for the content of every page being requested. You want to cache that page data in Redis, or cache the page response at the CDN, in order to reduce the database load.

Comment: I just converted to InnoDB, some tables were MyISAM some InnoDB and also did a CALL mysql.rds_rotate_slow_log;

Fingers crossed. Thank you, Mark, will look into doing this with Elasti-Cache if it's still crazy.

A $130/mo RDS for a wordpress site with 15 users / realtime does sound a bit like an overkill?

Comment: Yes it sounds like total overkill, and something that should be fixed with judicious use of caching.

Comment: I just managed to setup mysql-tuner, any input is much appreciated: http://pastebin.com/DTmbHeKj

Comment: Here's the best input available: never, under any circumstances, should anyone use mysql-tuner, or any similar script.   They tend to encourage you to tamper with parameters that should be left alone.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You're saying the params should remain default regardless of the specs or that I should try something different?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer an update:

Mark B's input has been extremely valuable as I have discovered that I can run mysql tuner remotely and touch the RDS. Therefore there was no need to migrate after all.

The RDS CPU spikes were due to a large amount of non-INDEX JOINs.
I have added indexes and the results are fantastic:

[image: RDS CPU spike problem solved via INDEX]